# json .get only acting on last element in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to refresh the images of my markers on a Google map. 
I am iterating through and array of markers and fetching new info from the server for them. They are fetching the right info for each marker in the array. But when they update the marker, it is the last one in the array being updated.

```
function refreshMarkerImages(markersArray){                                                                                                                                              

    for (index in markersArray){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        var markerObject = markersArray[index];                                                                                                                                              
        requestUrl = "/update_canvas_rain_pin_markers";                                                                                                                             
        requestParams = "rain_sensor=" + markerObject.rain_sensor_id;                                                                                                                        

        $.get(requestUrl, requestParams, function(response) {                                                                                                                                
            text  = response.split(",")[0];                                                                                                                                                  
            color = response.split(",")[1];                                                                                                                                                  
            markerObject.setMap(null);                                                                                                                                                       
            newImage = createMarkerCanvasIcon(text, color)                                                                                                                                   
            markerObject.setIcon(newImage);                                                                                                                                                  
            markerObject.setMap(map);                                                                                                                                                        
        })                                                                                                                                                                                 
    }    
}
```

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

this should fix it for you:

```
function refreshMarkerImages(markersArray) {
    for (index in markersArray) {

        (function (index) {//added closure index is now local to function
            var markerObject = markersArray[index];
            requestUrl = "/update_canvas_rain_pin_markers";
            requestParams = "rain_sensor=" + markerObject.rain_sensor_id;

            $.get(requestUrl, requestParams, function (response) {
                text = response.split(",")[0];
                color = response.split(",")[1];
                markerObject.setMap(null);
                newImage = createMarkerCanvasIcon(text, color)
                markerObject.setIcon(newImage);
                markerObject.setMap(map);
            });
        }(index))
    }
}
```

EDIT, Short explanation:
Since you are using an inner async function inside of a loop by the time the inner function is called the loop has already ended running, that's the reason why it is always on the last index.

I wrapped the code within a self invoking function that receives the index as a parameter and supplied that index in the invocation parentheses.

This created an execution context with the correct index for every call since the index is now a part of the code that was executed.

Comment: Remember that javascript scope hoists variables all the way to the function declaration. index, and every other variable actually have a scope of the entire function, not the for loop. The index changes at every loop, and when the first asynchronous call comes back, it's already looped through every loop, so `index` is the last number. What this answer does is scope the `index` to the inner function, which is what you wanted.

Comment: @DanCrewsI don't see how hoisting has anything to do with this issue

Comment: Hoisting is the problem that your solution fixes.

Comment: My solution fixes the problem of execution context and scope, not hoisting. n/m

Comment: You realize that the hoisting problem and the scoping problem are the same, yes?

Comment: It's not in this case but let's let it be, no need to argue

Comment: Thanks for this post. It has helped me to understand what happened, but i am not sure why. I will read up on it. I am kinda new with javascript and i suppose i expect it to act like ruby or python or sumsuch in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you understand what the JIT (just-in-time) compiler is doing to your code, you will understand better why this is happening.

```
// These variables were never initialized with "var", so they are globally scoped.
var index, requestUrl, requestParams, text, color, newImage;

function refreshMarkerImages(markersArray) {
  var markerObject;

  for (index in markersArray) {
    markerObject = markersArray[index];
    requestUrl = "/update_canvas_rain_pin_markers";
    requestParams = "rain_sensor=" + markerObject.rain_sensor_id;

    $.get(requestUrl, requestParams, function(response) {
      text = response.split(",")[0];
      color = response.split(",")[1];
      markerObject.setMap(null);
      newImage = createMarkerCanvasIcon(text, color)
      markerObject.setIcon(newImage);
      markerObject.setMap(map);
    })
  }
}
```

You can see that the `markerObject` you were expecting to be inside your loop is actually hoisted to the top of the scope, which in this case is the function. Each loop, they are all writing over the same variables, so whoever gets run last, wins.

You can understand even more when you see the way the process works:

Let's say

```
markersArray = [ 0, 1, 2];
```

1st tick:

```
index = 0
markerObject = something0
requestUrl = something0
requestParams = something0
ajaxResponse0 = somerequest0
index = 1
markerObject = something1
requestUrl = something1
requestParams = something1
ajaxResponse0 = somerequest1
index = 2
markerObject = something2
requestUrl = something2
requestParams = something2
ajaxResponse0 = somerequest2
```

Now it's done with all of the synchronous code, so the following ticks can happen:

```
HandleAjaxResponse0; // markerObject === something2
HandleAjaxResponse1; // markerObject === something2
HandleAjaxResponse2; // markerObject === something2
```

Notice you've already changed all of your `markerObject` with the synchronous code, so you no longer have access to the value you were expecting.

What you have to do instead is create a NEW variable for each pass of the loop, so that you don't lose context of the value you're expecting. You can either use the loop and a closure, or you can use Array.prototype.map, which is probably a better option, as this is what it's for:

```
function refreshMarkerImages(markersArray) {

  markersArray.map(function(markerObject) {
    var requestUrl = "/update_canvas_rain_pin_markers";
    var requestParams = "rain_sensor=" + markerObject.rain_sensor_id;

    $.get(requestUrl, requestParams, function(response) {
      var text = response.split(",")[0];
      var color = response.split(",")[1];
      markerObject.setMap(null);
      var newImage = createMarkerCanvasIcon(text, color)
      markerObject.setIcon(newImage);
      markerObject.setMap(map);
    })
  });

}
```

Comment: Dan, you need to edit your answer. the variables should be inside of the function, not above it.

Comment: @Saar that's incorrect. If you don't initialize the variables, they live in global scope (window.something). Because he didn't use `var` anywhere, those variables got defined globally, outside of his function. Technically, they aren't ever `var`ed anywhere, as he's actually defining `window.text`, etc, but I didn't think that was necessary to mention.

Comment: true, I saw the marker object on the top of the function and for some reason thought he defined the rest inside as well. I stand corrected.